# QEMU VM guest with no network in bridge mode on Arch Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, arch-linux, network-shares, bridge, qemu

I try to create a network bridge mode with my QEMU VM guest in Arch Linux using `systemd-networkd`.

First, I create bridge mode in Arch Linux:

```
# nano /etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev

[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
MACAddress=[My_own_MAC_address]
[Bridge]
VLANFiltering=1
STP=1


# nano /etc/systemd/network/br0enp2s0.network

[Match]
Name=enp2s0
[Network]
Bridge=br0


# nano /etc/systemd/network/br0.network

[Match]
Name=br0
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4


# systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service

# systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

# systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

Second, I configure and run my QEMU VM guest in Arch Linux:

```
# qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -monitor stdio \
        -cpu host \
        -device intel-hda \
        -device hda-duplex \
        -k es \
        -machine accel=kvm \
        -m 2048 \
        -hda ~/Windows.7.qcow2 \
        -boot once=c,menu=off \
        -netdev tap,id=tap_0_GROUP,br=br0,ifname=tap_0_GROUP,script=no,vhost=on,downscript=no \
        -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=tap_0_GROUP,mac=[My_own_MAC_address] \
        -usb -device usb-tablet \
        -rtc base=localtime \
        -name "Windows 7"
    
    QEMU 8.1.2 monitor - type 'help' for more information
    (qemu)
```

QEMU guest boots correctly but no network:
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPKPe.png)

Comment: Please do not [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1816740/revisions) to say “SOLVED!” If there is an answer, then check it off as the answer as you did for [Tom Yan’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1816747/167207) and that’s it. Editing a question to add an answer only caused confusion; this is not a message board but a site that already has an “Answer” mechanism built it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `bridge` netdev instead, which AFAIK is the same as the `tap` one with the `helper=` param set properly.

If you use the `tap` one without the using the helper (usually found at `/usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper`), you probably need a `script=` that enslave the tap to the bridge and set the tap `up`. (In other words, the `br=` does not really have any effect without `helper=` set.)

Note that the helper needs you to whitelist the bridge to use by having `allow br0` in `/etc/qemu/bridge.conf`.

With the helper (because it has setuid) the need of being root for setting up the tap is also eliminated.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom Yan. Right, it's better to use qemu-bridge-helper.